# Why i cant see image in the example of material -ui-next "Cards"?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

[This example](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/) comes from material-ui-next website but somehow I can't see the image which is the "lizard image" when I try to run it on my computer.

Why can see the image? I got no error in my console and the "simple card" example in the website is working to me but not the one with image like "Lizard". (I think my error is in the path of image or src of image)

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const styles = {
  card: {
    maxWidth: 345,
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: '56.25%', // 16:9
  },
};

function SimpleMediaCard(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardMedia
          className={classes.media}
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          title="Contemplative Reptile"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="headline" component="h2">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography component="p">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000 species, ranging
            across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
        <CardActions>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Share
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" color="primary">
            Learn More
          </Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleMediaCard.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleMediaCard);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now i know, I change the path of Image to**

```
  import logo from './lizard.jpg';
         <CardMedia
              className={classes.media}
              image={logo}
              title="Contemplative Reptile"
            />
```

Comment: Do we have any other way to do this? like inline path?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some url to image, you probably have to use `img` component and give its path in `src`.

```
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  src={url}
                />
```